# AWS-SDK in nodejs Lambda function cannot find endpoint-cache module

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I've been refactoring some of our AWS lambda functions and with this most recent version I am getting the following error:

```
"Payload": "{\"errorMessage\":\"Cannot find module '../vendor/endpoint-cache'\",\"errorType\":\"Error\",\"stackTrace\":[\"Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)\",\"Module.require (module.js:596:17)\",\"require (internal/module.js:11:18)\",\"Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/core.js:76:18)\",\"Module._compile (module.js:652:30)\",\"Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)\",\"Module.load (module.js:565:32)\",\"tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)\",\"Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)\"]}"
```

This module is within the vendor folder of the aws-sdk node module.
I checked the deployment artifacts to make sure that the folder exists and I've tried downgrading to the older version of the aws-sdk that was being used before.

Dependencies in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.59.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  },
```

The build server runs npm-install and then

```
$path = Get-Location
$thisProject = "$($path)\pathToProject\*"

Compress-Archive -Path $thisProject -DestinationPath thisProject.zip
```

Been stuck on this for a while so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Temporary fix: Use a version earlier than v2.352.0.

I'm in the same boat. I've narrowed down the problem to `aws-sdk` referencing a new feature `endpoint-cache` introduced in release https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/releases/tag/v2.352.0 found on a change on this line https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/cbef86432191d1501075d71744385c273c4bbc3a/lib/core.js#L76. AWS lambda's Node 8.10 can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this issue a few months back. Turns out I needed to make sure the package lock file was included in the project and had the aws-sdk version set

Comment: Also need to make sure its updating with the right version :)

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue yesterday, I solved it by removing the `aws-sdk` in the `package.json` & deleting + reinstalling my `node_modules` folder. Hope this solves your problem.

I think the `aws-sdk` is already included by default.

Answer (score 2):

I actually encountered the same problem. And in my case the reason was in the `Compress-Archive` function, run on Windows. If I pack lambda with `Compress-Archive`, then Lambda call fails with the error in question above. But if I unpack `.zip` and pack with regular Windows "send to compressed directory" - everything works fine. I've found some [similar issue in PowerShell github space](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2140), which made me think this is a common problem.

The problem was fixed in one of the latest releases of PowerShell Core (not sure about classic PowerShell). I'm not sure about the exact release which fixes this problem, but it was there in v.6.1, and in v.6.2.2 it's gone.

Comment: Your a hero.... I was using an multiple versions of powershell. Making sure I was running 7.0 core fixed the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach to specifying the SDK you want in a Lambda function is to create a lambda layer with your desired version. See here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/working-with-aws-lambda-and-lambda-layers-in-aws-sam/